# CLGeocoder doesn't return any placemarks

Tags: ios, cllocation, clgeocoder

I have some problem with CLGeocoder, it doesn't return any value for Polish street name:

```
"Suwalska 3 Wrocław"
```

I  use this method to download coordinate:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Suwalska 3 Wrocław" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
}];
```

Why for example string geocoder does not return anything? I found also other example streets when geocoder won't work. Why google maps/emaps/ can show "Suwalska 3 Wrocław" on map by geocoder does not return anything. Should I use google API for ios insted? So even if apple does not support such big street in Poland why people should use geocoder. I think this is some kind of missunderstanding from Apple.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try converting the string to plain ascii? so "Suwalska 3 Wroclaw"? Or do you get any error in the completion block?

Comment: Yes i have tried but not reason, I dont have any error with downloading. Now I noticed that this streen not occure on apple maps. So when you open apple maps and type: Suwalska Wrocław, there is no reason.